# JList never get updated

Tags: java, swing

After the user buy something from the machine, the machine should update the quantity. How do I update the quantity?

The loop works fine and in debug mode, it shows i and newQty value. 
This code in GUI class.

```
char letter = 'A';
        for (int i = 0; i < stock.length;) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 7 && i < stock.length; j++) {
                stock[i].setId(letter + "" + j);
                i++;
            }
            letter++;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ++i) {
   listModel.addElement(stock[i].getId() + ": " + stock[i].getDescription() 
  + " - " + stock[i].getPrice() + "(" + stock[i].getQuantity() + ")");

        }

        listOfItem.setModel(listModel);
```

In actionPerformed() I have this code.

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Vend!")) {

        for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ++i) {

            if (userSelection.equals(stock[i].getId())) {
                if (userBalance < stock[i].getPrice()) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have enough money. "
        + "Please add more money or select a different item.");

            }

                else if (stock[i].getQuantity() == 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, we are out of this item.");
                }

        else {

            int newQty = stock[i].getQuantity() - 1;
            stock[i].setQuantity(newQty);

            userBalance -= stock[i].getPrice();

            MoneyRemainingText.setText(String.valueOf(userBalance));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You bought " + stock[i].getDescription() + " for $"
                    + stock[i].getPrice() + ". Your change is $" + userBalance);
            vendingMachine.setVisible(false);

            selectTextField.setText("");

            --userBalance;

            setSelection();

        }
    }
        }
    }
```

Here some pics. So, you can see what's going on with (quantity)

A1: Coke - 1.25(1) should be A1: Coke - 1.25 **(0)**[image: box]
After buying it.

[image: box1]

[image: box2]

Comment: Hard to say with the code provided. What is `listModel`? You only adds elements to the list model. Probably you see the old ones plus the new ones at the end (?).

Comment: the quantity never get updated in the box. For example, if the Coke has (1) qty, it should be 0 after the user buy a coke.

Comment: It is a txt file with some item name, price, qty.

Comment: @PeterMmm Should I add the entire code for testing?

Comment: If possible, you should provide a [mcve] that shows your problem.

Comment: *"Should I add the entire code for testing?"* No, as advised by @PeterMmm, post an MCVE. To replace the 'text file', hard code some data in variables of the code.

Comment: i think you should update the model, not the stock array, as this will not affect the model and the displayed data. (update the stock array for sake of sync, if you push it back to the file or to a DB?) , but also update the model related item in order to update the display

Answer (score 0):

Using a list here is a mistake.
List is smething that u append a price and it is added on the stack.

However If you want to save the day try

```
model.setElementAt("Your new text", index);
```

The only obligation you have here is to get the 
index(line number you want to edit).

PS:I would need more code , to debbug.

Answer (score 0):

> You must update your jList on each successful operation

Suppose your first code block method is `updateJList()`

```
public void updateJlist(){
        listModel.removeAllElements();//first clear previous items 
        char letter = 'A';
        for (int i = 0; i < stock.length;) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 7 && i < stock.length; j++) {
                stock[i].setId(letter + "" + j);
                i++;
            }
            letter++;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ++i) {
   listModel.addElement(stock[i].getId() + ": " + stock[i].getDescription() 
  + " - " + stock[i].getPrice() + "(" + stock[i].getQuantity() + ")");

        }

        listOfItem.setModel(listModel);

}
```

Now when you make any successful operation to buy a product update your jList by calling updateJList() method

In `actionPerfromed`

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Vend!")) {

    for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; ++i) {

        if (userSelection.equals(stock[i].getId())) {
            if (userBalance < stock[i].getPrice()) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have enough money. "
    + "Please add more money or select a different item.");

        }

            else if (stock[i].getQuantity() == 0) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, we are out of this item.");
            }

    else {

        int newQty = stock[i].getQuantity() - 1;
        stock[i].setQuantity(newQty);

        userBalance -= stock[i].getPrice();

        MoneyRemainingText.setText(String.valueOf(userBalance));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You bought " + stock[i].getDescription() + " for $"
                + stock[i].getPrice() + ". Your change is $" + userBalance);
        vendingMachine.setVisible(false);

        selectTextField.setText("");

        --userBalance;

        setSelection();

        updateJlist(); // here your list will update with new values
    }
}
    }
}
```